# How do I analyze Visual Studio 2010 Load Test Results?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I've successfully run a number of load tests with vs2010 and I am now trying to analyise the results.

I have two agents that the tests are using and I'm not sure if both agents are executing tests.
I see **Avg. Test Time** for one agent only.

Is it possible to get the number of tests executed per agent, rather than the whole Load test?

Answer (score 3):

First, double-check in your Test Settings ('Test' menu > Edit test settings...) under 'Roles' that the Test execution method is 'Remote execution' and you have your Controller specified.  Maybe you ran in local mode by accident.

If you are looking at the 'Agents' table in the load test results and it is only showing one agent, I would assume you're right that only the one agent executed tests.

<sub>[I *believe* that if there was a communication problem between Controller and Agent that prevented the Agent from talking back to the Controller, then the Controller would not push tests down to it.  But if this were the case then we should expect to see a message in the error list about that.]</sub>

One way to see if your other agent is actually running tests is to open the 'Manage Test Controller' dialog during a test run ('Test' menu > Manage Test Controllers...).  The running agents will have status 'Running tests'.

Another (roundabout) way to see whether or not an agent is executing tests is to run the load test with 'Timing Details Storage' (in the LoadTest RunSettings) set to 'All Individual Details'.  Then when the test is complete you can click the 'Detail' button (next to 'Summary', 'Graphs', and 'Tables') in the load test result and see the detailed chart of virtual user activity.  *If I recall correctly* you can mouseover the chart and the popup text will tell you the name of the agent that ran that particular virtual user.

If I recall wrongly, you can click on the chart line and pull up the WebTest log for that test, and you can find the agent name in the Context Parameters of the test.  But this requires that you have set 'Save Log Frequency for Completed Tests' (again in RunSettings) to 1 so that the WebTest logs are saved.